# How to store and query infinite nested parent children relationships

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to find the most efficient manner of storing and querying this data structure.

Food Objects Table:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qs808.png

Food Relationships Table:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XFgK.png

Desired resulting JSON when I query food where id = '8a2d7fde-13ef-4403-92a4-fcf518f27641'
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPMgm.png

So basically a food object can have an array of instances of any other food object along with custom settings/props/values for each instance/reference. Each instance can have its own children infinitely expanding down the tree as deep as the user wants to define the objects.

Comment: what is a triplestore?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by triplestore?

Comment: Please don’t link to images in your question. Add all relevant information directly to your question, preferably as editable text

Comment: Sorry I didnt know how to write a table in text. And stack overflow did that when I added an image.

Comment: Tables: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support

Comment: You seem perilously close to "The Semantic Web", "Ontologies" , "RDF" and "SPARQL" to query ntriples (in a triplestore).   It _will_ work for limited cases, but at some point in scale you will notice that you now have 2 problems.

Comment: Consider https://foodon.org/